# The Geocoding api returns a wrong location for a pincode, but Google maps returns right location

Tags: api, google-maps, geocoding

I used the pincode (400036) in the geocoding webservice, but got a location in China. The webservice is shared below.

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=india&components=postal_code:400036&sensor=false

Ideally it should be a location in Mumbai (Bombay) in the state of Maharashtra, India.
Any ideas why this could occur?
Also, any other parameters that can be passed to make this particular pin code work?

Thanks and regards,
Anand

P.S.: I'm a Business Analyst, so my technical know-how and command of programming languages is pretty limited. However, I'll be most happy to receive help from the community here and pass it on to my dev team. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Geocoding and working with real-world data is hard, and not even the great Google (no sarcasm, I'm a fan) gets it right all the time.  Apparently there is a software or data bug in the Google API, since this works (added Country India to the component filter):

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:400001%7Ccountry:IN&sensor=false

But this does not, and is not even filtering by country because it still returns Chinese results:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:400036%7Ccountry:IN&sensor=false

If you're a paying customer, you can contact Google for support here: http://www.google.com/enterprise/portal

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://geoanalyzer.in for this. Google maps and google api are slighly different as Google Maps shows you results from both Google Maps API and also from Google places hence a lot of time you get wrong data in case of Google Maps API. Geo Analyzer solved this and has been built specifically for Indian addresses.

This is one of the few available solutions that is targeted for Indian address system complexity. I hope this will help.